# Google Extensions - Custom Cursor

Tags: manifest

What manifest version should I use for making a Custom Cursor Chrome Extension? I have tried looking all over at developer.chrome.com but I just cant find it!

Help would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: The only available option is Manifest v2? Manifest v1 has been deprecated and v3 will be 'released'(allowed on the web store) on January 2021.

Comment: Hi @ChilliPenguin, I meant format. Sorry, I put it in my wrong words. As In what Sources Backrounds ECT>

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/manifest/)? It holds all possible manifest options. For a custom clicker I would think it would only need to inject a bit of css to the webpage(via js); which would be probably a ['content script'](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/content_scripts//) and [browser action](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/browserAction/) as a menu.